# Pretty routing with total.js (like 'base_url/@username')

Tags: javascript, total.js

I'm new to node.js, have been using Ruby and RoR.

I'd like to show a view for user view with a pretty routing.

In Rails, I can handle with code like this:

```
get '@:username' => 'users#show'
```

So I tried in Total.js as same, but error appeaerd with `404: Not found`:

```
exports.install = function() {
  F.route('/@{username}', view_user);
}
```

How can I get my user view with `localhost:8000/@my_name` in total.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove `@` from the route:

```
exports.install = function() {
    F.route('/{username}/', view_user);
};

function view_user(username) {
    if (!username.startsWith('@')) {
        this.throw404();
    else
        this.plain(username);
});
```

Thanks.